# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input:checkbox[name=ninja_forms_field_57[terms]]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to limit the number of checkboxes that can be checked within a form, but am getting the following error:

**Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input:checkbox[name=ninja_forms_field_57[terms]]**

Here is the Javascript that I'm using:

```
// Main Category
var $checkboxes_to_limit2 = $("#taxonomy_47").find("input:checkbox[name=ninja_forms_field_47[terms]]");
$checkboxes_to_limit2.live("change", function() {
    if($checkboxes_to_limit2.filter(":checked").length >= 3) {
    $checkboxes_to_limit2.not(":checked").attr("disabled","disabled");
    }
    else {
        $checkboxes_to_limit2.removeAttr("disabled");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to treat the name attribute as a string, so

```
input:checkbox[name=ninja_forms_field_47[terms]]
```

should be

```
input:checkbox[name='ninja_forms_field_47[terms]']
```

Answer (score 0):

You need some additional single quotes:

```
var $checkboxes_to_limit2 =
  $("#taxonomy_47").find("input:checkbox[name='ninja_forms_field_47[terms]']")
```